# java code analysis and structure by tool or pluggin

Tags: java, eclipse, code-analysis

Is there any tool that helps analyse code structure in a java project, either as an eclipse pluggin or as a standalone?
I guess something similar to what Structure101 seems to do, but I am looking for something free.
I.e. to visualize dependencies among jars, classes, class-hierarchies etc.
It is mostly to understand an existing code-base faster, rather than set coding rules or profile etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following tools useful

1. CodePro Analytics - http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html
2. JDepend - http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html
3. Sonar - http://www.sonarsource.org/
4. Metrics - http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

Comment: CodePro's Eclipse plugin doesn't resolve to a reachable site when updating.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)?

Comment: I am looking for something to to visualize dependencies among jars, classes, class-hierarchies etc.It is mostly to understand an existing code-base faster, rather than set coding rules or profile etc.Does Sonar help on this??

Comment: oh, take a look to JDepend http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html is the best IMHO tool to inspect dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Tons of them.  The thing is you probably want to google for the kinds of tests, eg, "McCabe complexity java" or "test coverage java".

You might have a look at [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis).

**Update**

Aha.  Try [depfind](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/).